# Indexing filenames in the fileadmin-folder for user search purposes

Tags: typo3

Is there an easy way to configure the TYPO3 Extension [indexed_search](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/indexed_search/latest/) so that it finds files in the fileadmin-folder. I would like that the search function on the TYPO3-website compares the searchquery with filenames, too. For example:

I have a "example.pdf" in my fileadmin folder. When the user types in: "example" in the search-field then the result should be a link to the example.pdf.

Thanks in advance

Comment: afaik, indexed_search only indexes those files, which are found on web-site pages. Maybe it makes sense to create some hidden in menu page, which contains a plugin, showing all the files in fileadmin (or any other folder) and crawl it periodically with `crawler` extension.

Comment: Ok i will try this

Comment: as *indexed search* is capabale to index any kind of records and since TYPO3 6.0 all files have a record (FAL) you should configure to index these records. Alas you still need a page where to present the link to the file. But instead of showing links to all files I would try to use a plugin which redirects (with apropiate parameter) to the file only.